# Cake PHP foreignkey issues

Tags: database, cakephp

So I am using cakephp and I am a little new to this and I am facing certain issues.

1) I have two tables, report and issues.

cakephp:

```
report{id, type, details}
issue{id,report_id, details}
```

So now I am trying to get the report id in issues table. I have defined my hasmany and belongsto relationships as follows:

```
class Report extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Report';

    var $hasMany = array(

'AtneIssue' => array(
'className' => 'Issue',
'foreignKey' => 'report_id',
'dependent' => true,
        )

    );
}

class Issue extends AppModel {
        var $name = 'Issue';


        var $belongsTo = array(
            'Report' => array(
                'className' => 'Report',
                'foreignKey' => 'report_id',
                'conditions' => '',
                'fields' => '',
                'order' => ''
        )
        );
    }
```

But this results in a sql error and the data not being saved to the table. I have set index to report_id to get id from Report.

Data is getting saved to reports but not to issues table.

Can someone tell me how to go about this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first letter is replace by number here. dunno why... I figured how to post data But now I am not able to get the ID of the report and the data is getting corrupted like below:                  Query: INSERT INTO `atne_issues` (`status`, `issue_owner`, `issue_reason`, `problem`) VALUES ('2nhold', '2ricsson', '2IQ - IP address incorrect', '2sdfasdf')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first letter is replace by number here. dunno why... I figured how to post data But now I am not able to get the ID of the report and the data is getting corrupted like below:

```
Query: INSERT INTO `atne_issues` (`status`, `issue_owner`, `issue_reason`, `problem`) VALUES ('2nhold', '2ricsson', '2IQ - IP address incorrect', '2sdfasdf')
```

Comment: Hmm probably you're replacing the first letter with 2 somewhere in the code? It's hard to say without all of the code visible.